# Passing multiple parameters to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax

I have a function which is as follows:

```
//Calling the Function with one Parameter
responses(baseURL);

//Function Definition
function responses(baseURL) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL,
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.features.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                if (taxArrayT1.indexOf(data.features[i].properties.taxon_id) == -1) {
                    taxArrayT1.push(data.features[i].properties.taxon_id);
                }
            }
            console.log("In the Invertebrate Animals Section 1");
            console.log(taxArrayT1.length);
        }
    })
}
```

Now I tend to repeat myself because when I hit different services with the same function. I know how to pass the base URL as a parameter. Also there is an array like in this example, `taxArrayT1`. This array changes every time a different input is used, like `taxArrayT2`. It would be great if you have suggestions on how to accomplish. It would be of great help.

Comment: You can just define your function as `function responses(baseURL, taxArray){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then you can just add the array as a second parameter. Like this:

```
function responses(baseURL, taxArray) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL,
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.features.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                if (taxArray.indexOf(data.features[i].properties.taxon_id) == -1) {
                    taxArray.push(data.features[i].properties.taxon_id);
                }
            }
            console.log("In the Invertebrate Animals Section 1");
            console.log(taxArray.length);
        }
    })
}
```

And the service calls will look like this:

```
responses(url1, taxArrayT1);
responses(url2, taxArrayT1);
```